# Ajax, PHP. How can i send multiple variable with _GET or anyother way to other file?

Tags: ajax

Im trying to send two variables with get to a php file that contains an xlm format

```
function process(){

if (xmlHttp){
    try{
     email = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("email").value);
     if (email=="") {email="empty email"};
     xmlHttp.open("GET", "user_check.php?email=" + email, true);

    username = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("username").value);
    if (username=="") {username="empty username"};
    xmlHttp.open("GET", "user_check.php?username=" + username, true);
```

the php file looks like

```
echo '<response>';
    echo '<username>';
         $username = ( isset($_GET['username']) ? $_GET['username'] : "something empty");
            echo $username;

    echo '</username>';

    echo '<email>';
        $email = ( isset($_GET['email']) ? $_GET['email'] : "something empty");
        echo $email;

    echo '</email>';

echo '</response>';
```

when i echo those variables it shows only one, actually it sends only the username which is the second on list(from top to bottom) that is sent. How can i send both or later more variables

```
function handleResponse(){
     message_email = xmlHttp.responseXML.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("email").item(0).firstChild.data;
    next_email = document.getElementById("next_email");
    next_email.innerHTML =message_email;

 message_username = xmlHttp.responseXML.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("username").item(0).firstChild.data;
    next_username = document.getElementById("next_username");
    next_username.innerHTML =message_username;
}
```

the output of this is

email : something empty

username : "the value from input"

i want email to have its value from its input.

I hope i made my question clear.

Comment: you have to send the two values in one call `xmlHttp.open("GET", "user_check.php?username=" + username + "&email="+email, true);`

Comment: thanks alot , it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can understand you, you have to put both of variables into one request, because now, you are sending two requests, after everything reading only second one.

To send two variables in one GET request you use something like:

```
http://example.com/response.php?var1=foo&var2=bar
```

resulting in PHP:

```
$_GET['var1'] = "foo";
$_GET['var2'] = "bar";
```

So your AJAX code should look like:

```
email = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("email").value);
if (email=="") {
 email="empty email"
};

username = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("username").value);
if (username=="") {
 username="empty username"
};

xmlHttp.open("GET", "user_check.php?email=" + email + "&username=" + username, true);
```

Important thing is that order of GET variables doesn't matter - you can put email or username first, they will both be loaded into $_GET[] array.

Comment: If this answer seems good for you, please, mark it as solving your problem ;)